# Dell latitude d630 not turning on?

Tags: laptop, debian, battery, shutdown, dell-latitude

The problem occurs yesterday when my laptop suddenly freeze then I shutdown it using power button but when try to turn on it does not.

I tried to hard boot but not working.
So i thinks to remove battery for night and today I insert battery and try to turn on and it works but i shutdown and open after sometime later the problem arrives again.

When I continuously keep turning on laptop the numberpad, capslock and scroll lock are glowing sometimes.

Please help me out.
Laptop
Dell latitude d630 second hand 12 months old.
Os
Debian 11 Bullseye lxqt

Comment: Can you run it plugged in without the battery

Comment: Yes did this too but not working.

Comment: If it is under 1 year old, it is still under warranty.

Comment: It is has No warranty, It different story. Did you know any fix about that problem.

Comment: Is it plugged in and charging?

Comment: A Dell latitude d630 is a very old and outdated laptop. Intel Core 2 Duo and originally shipped with XP or Vista. This should give anyone with basic knowledge an idea of how old it is. Saying "12 months old" is ridiculously misleading. You may have bought if second hand a year ago but it's a laptop from 2007. Who knows what abuse it has endured before or in the last year... The point being it failed due to old age and a repair is probably not worth it as it can easily double the actual market value of such old hardware.

Comment: @ChanganAuto i am not misleading I bought it from someone.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik yes charging.

Comment: Sure but that's totally irrelevant. It IS misleading because it suggests to anyone that it's new. I knew immediately that wasn't the case because I'm a bit familiar with Dell models but anyone not familiar with it would have to google the model number to find out.

Comment: @changanAuto if this look like it's new then I will edit it but still I am not misleading I just want a solution because there was some important data stored in this laptop and want back.

Comment: 1. When asking for help giving proper and relevant information is key. The age of the hardware is relevant information, when you actually bought it used is NOT. **And, again, very misleading, someone in comments though it was still in warranty!!!** Now, it very likely needs repair, something the you probably can't do, let alone random people in the internet. If you want to recover data then your best bet is to remove the HDD and connect it to another computer. But **if the data is important then you should have backups**. Keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: @ChanganAuto i understand that i didn't provide the proper information about hardware it's my mistake and thanks for suggestion but i dont have a mind to mislead someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I remove and insert first ram behind the laptop. But it not works on first day so i leave it again for a night but this time i leave the battery inserted. On morning I try to open but does not work at all, again I tried this in afternoon but the screen come back and show the battery low then I plugin the charge and suddenly laptop freeze its like previous time. Sometime later I start it again and screen came while showing low battery but i didn't not plugin this time. After window is loaded(yeah i have two os "debian 11 and windows 10") I put the ac adapter it's charging but charge is not increasing so i leave it in that state and start recovering my data after that i shutdown the laptop. In night it shows the battery was low again but it is charging. Everything is fine now!!!. So i decided to clean it by removing linux(linux is not junk) and junk files.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: FYI, Dell's Preboot Diagnostic Test can be useful for troubleshooting such issues - https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-au/000181163/how-to-enter-the-built-in-diagnostics-32-bit-diagnostics-supportassist-epsa-epsa-and-psa PS: thats a cool old lappy, a good solid build, though, why you'd ditch Debian for W10 is beyond me! :-)